# ROS Base_link to laser_link TF. When the relationship btwn base_link to laser_link is unknown or has error

Tags: coordinates, frame, ros, calibration

I have looked up a lot of papers to figure this out but I need some help guys.

I am currently working on transforming coordinate frame from Base_link to laser_link. In tuturials, we assume that the relationship between laser and base is known.

However, I would like to know if is there anyway to calibrate this relationship assuming that the relationship contains error or is unknown. Thank you guys!

Comment: I think more info is needed here. What are the constraints around your robot and the sensor operating in `laser_link`? At the very least, if your sensor and robot are not attached the robot would need to be generating some form of reliable odometry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.